# Cant set Navigation title colours on IOS 13+ using Appearance xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

So firstly i have looked through numerous articles and answers over this issue but had no luck resolving it.

The app will be running ios 13+ so theres no issues with backwards compatibility around IOS's appearance API.

I have a shared static function i call to set the appearance properties on my navigation controllers. I did initially set this in the app delegate so it would be applied globally but the titleText and largeTitleText attributes were not being applied. For the moment in ViewDidLoad i call this function to set the properties.

```
public static void DefaultNavigationBarAppearence(UINavigationController navigationController)
{
    if(navigationController == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var appearence = new UINavigationBarAppearance();
    appearence.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromName("Primary");
    appearence.TitleTextAttributes.ForegroundColor = UIColor.White;
    appearence.LargeTitleTextAttributes.ForegroundColor = UIColor.White;

    navigationController.NavigationBar.Translucent = false;
    navigationController.NavigationBar.PrefersLargeTitles = true;
    navigationController.NavigationBar.StandardAppearance = appearence;
    navigationController.NavigationBar.CompactAppearance = appearence;
    navigationController.NavigationBar.ScrollEdgeAppearance = appearence;
}
```

But no matter what i do i cant change the text colour on my titles, i am using large titles. But they always just show as black text as you can see below.

[image]

Am i missing something obvious here? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `UIStringAttributes` to set its color:

```
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.PrefersLargeTitles = true;
this.NavigationController.NavigationItem.LargeTitleDisplayMode = UINavigationItemLargeTitleDisplayMode.Always;
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.LargeTitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes()
    {
       ForegroundColor = UIColor.White
    };
```

Comment: UIStringAttributes did the job, don't know why setting ForegroundColor directly did not work though. Thank you.